# I want to index specific values in a specific range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of students that I have the following mark criteria,

1. from `0` to `-500`
2. from `-501` to `-1000`
3. from `-1001` to `-5000`
4. from `-5001` to `-10000000000`

The list of students and the categorization were on sheet 1. On sheet 2 I have the criteria as headers.

I want a formula that I can use under lets say criteria 1 
and it automatically fills all the account numbers that met the criteria under the column that has that criteria as a header.

Sheet 2:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried a PivotTable?

Comment: I have but the people im working with cannot keep updating the tablet data source every time they add a new account that's why I'm looking for a formula

Comment: Have a look at countifs(), sumifs(), there are examples around on here...

Comment: A formula won't work you will need VBA, but because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: ive tried index with match but the formula only takes the first account number that fits the criteria and ignores the rest, I've tired pivot tables but the people im working for would like it dynamic rather than them wanting to go and change the data source every time, so im pretty much stuck and im not that strong with VBA that's why i came here to ask

Comment: @ThaerJ Was your question resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this array formula (ctrl+shift+enter !!) :
`{=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$5;SMALL(IF((B$1:B$5>-1000)*($B$1:$B$5<=-500);ROW(A$1:A$5)-ROW(A$1)+1);ROWS(A$1:A1)));"")}`

I hard coded the cut-off values, but this would be better of course with a reference to the cells above where you put the cut-off values (so you not only can copy down, but also copy right). In `A$1:A$5` are the students/accounts, and in `B$1:B$5` their scores. You can copy this formula down in each target column, ideally as far down as there are rows in your original list (just to cover the --probably unlikely-- case that all students' scores are in the same bracket...)
Of course change the `;` delimiter with `,` if needed according to your regional settings.

Credit to this answer on SU : https://superuser.com/a/692580/681891

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to enter all your data into each column, and then sort by your criteria. Each column would contain all the data, but only display the desired fields.
No VBA necessary.

Comment: i understand but that means it will have to be done manually each time, which is why they assigned this project for me, i have to make it dynamic (to sort all results based on the criteria without manual intervention) ive tried index with match but it only takes the first result that applies to the criteria